# How to Disable Single Click in DataGridView and Select Record by Double Click Only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

What I want to do is to disable single click selection from DataGridView and Just use Double Click to Select Record.
I have searched a lot but didn't find the answer.

Can AnyBody Please Help Me?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't but one of my client want this

Comment: Why does your client want to do this?

Comment: Disable single click **select** or single click **edit**?

Comment: @RezaAghaei single click select row disable

Comment: Current row and Selected row are different. Current row shows an indicator on row header and selected row will be shown as highlighted. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Both selected and current

Answer (score 0):

The `EditMode` of the grid can be set to `EditProgrammatically`. You can then handle the `CellDoubleClick` event and call `BeginEdit`.